# mysql : show processlist "Locked"

Tags: mysql

When I run `show processlist`, it show me the result below:

```
--------------
| 396405 | root | localhost | biometrics | Query   |   465 | Locked       | UPDATE logins set login = 'xxxx', application_code = 'xxx', identity_uid = 'xxxxxx |
------------
```

The Application starting hang.

Comment: Is this the only process or are there others?

Comment: when it show "locked" , the Application will be hang

Comment: "Locked" state says "Locked: The query is locked by another query" so this is probably not the only active query and there are more entries in the processlist ...

If "logins" is a MyISAM table then any other active query on that table will have it locked (MyISAM only supports table level locks).

Or the table was locked explicitly by LOCK TABLES ... this can e.g happen when a mysqldump operation is running in parallel ...

Comment: how to solved this locked?